# Functional component renders twice only after deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I have functional component that renders Slider basing on window width:

```
const Works = (props) => {
  const size = useWindowWidth()
  const codeWorksArray = CodeWorksQuery()
  const mapWorksArray = MapWorksMetadata()

  const setSliderItems = (width) => {
    if (width > config.deviceWidths.medium) {
      return 4
    } else if (width >= config.deviceWidths.small) {
      return 2
    } else {
      return 1
    }
  }
...

<Slider sliderElements={mapWorksSliderItems} slidesCount={setSliderItems(size.width)}/>
```

`useWindowWidth()` is a hook that gets the window dimensions and handles resize listener:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const useWindowWidth = () => {
  const isWindowAvailable = typeof window !== "undefined"

  const getSize = () => {
    return {
      width: isWindowAvailable ? window.innerWidth : undefined,
      height: isWindowAvailable ? window.innerHeight : undefined
    };
  }

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isWindowAvailable) {
      return false
    }

    const handleResize = () => {
      setWindowSize(getSize())
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize)
  }, [])

  return windowSize
}

export default useWindowWidth
```

`slidesCount` value is passed as props to `Slider`, and the width of each slider item inside component is calculated. The problem is that once deployed the slider has only one element (instead of 4 on desktop). Seems that is updating only after resizing.

On localhost this works fine. After deployment (Netlify) this component renders twice, but after second render it keeps the information from first render.
What causes the difference in appearance on localhost and after deployment?

Comment: It seems that adding an event listener is missed. Do you use SSR?

Comment: It wasn't missing in my code, but here indeed - I forgot to copy the line with `addEventListener`. I don't know what's SSR in Gatsby (yet).